# How to pass the dynamic fieldName in filter condition of dataweave mule

Tags: mule, mule-studio, mule-component, mule-el, mule-esb

I have data in cache i.e objectstore. I need to get the data from cache and apply the filter condition on it.

Here requirement is, I have to expose api to get the data based on filedName and filedValue which will come dynamically in the request.

sample request :

```
https://localhost:8082/api/customer/filter?fieldName=customerId&fieldValue=101810
```

I have return code to filter the data in dataweave but it is not working. can you please help on this

```
%dw 1.0
%output application/json
---
payload.rows filter (("$.content." ++ flowVars.fieldName ++ ".content") as :string == flowVars.fieldValue as :string) map ((row , indexOfRow) -> {
    customerId: row.content.customerId.content as :string when row.content.customerId.content != null otherwise null,
    customerName: row.content.customerName.content as :string when row.content.customerName.content != null otherwise null,
    customerAddress:row.content.customerAddress.content as :string when row.content.customerAddress.content != null otherwise null
})
```

and I am getting below error

```
Exception while executing: 
payload.rows filter (("$.content." ++ flowVars.fieldName ++ ".content") as :string == flowVars.fieldValue as :string) map ((row , indexOfRow) -> {
                      ^
Type mismatch for '++' operator
     found :object, :string
  required :string, :string.
```

can you please help on this

Comment: please post code which is used for setting fieldName and fieldValue in objectstore or flowVars

Comment: we are getting them as query params which will come from request like this 
 fieldName=customerId&fieldValue=101810

Comment: from above mapping we will get fieldName as customerId or CustomerName or CustomerAddress to filter the data and filedVaule is corresponding value of that field. can you please help on this

Comment: please find input(json) as {
 "rows": [{
   "label": "530",
   "content": {
    "customerId": {
     "content": 100002
    },
    "customerName": {
     "content": "John"
    },
    "customerAddress": {
     "content": "US"
    }
   }
  },
  {
   "label": "530",
   "content": {
    "customerId": {
     "content": 100003
    },
    "customerName": {
     "content": "David"
    },
    "customerAddress": {
     "content": "san diego"
    }
   }
  }
 ]
}

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The issue is with the code used for selector it should be like `$.content[flowVars.fieldName].content`. Complete code will be

```
%dw 1.0
%output application/json
---
payload.rows filter (($.content[flowVars.fieldName].content) as :string == flowVars.fieldValue as :string) map ((row , indexOfRow) -> {
    customerId: row.content.customerId.content as :string when row.content.customerId.content != null otherwise null,
    customerName: row.content.customerName.content as :string when row.content.customerName.content != null otherwise null,
    customerAddress:row.content.customerAddress.content as :string when row.content.customerAddress.content != null otherwise null
})
```

This worked fine with the input provided by you.

Hope this help.

Comment: It works fine.Thanks @anupambhusari. Where we can find documentation on related to this. can you please provide me the link

Comment: Please refer [Dataweave Selector](https://docs.mulesoft.com/mule-user-guide/v/3.8/dataweave-selectors#alternative-syntax).